# Printing on multiple pages from a user form

Tags: excel, vba

On a form there is a text box containing 3634 characters. This is more than can be on an A4 page, so characters over 3500 must be printed on page 2.

I have tried the code below, but only page 1 is printed, the last 634 characters are not printed on page 2 as expected.

```
Private Sub Udskriv_Click()

' Skift til det aktive ark
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

' Navn på Frame
Dim frameNavn As String
frameNavn = "Redegørelse"

' Gem skærmopdateringens aktuelle tilstand
Dim oldScreenUpdating As Boolean
oldScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating

' Deaktiver skærmopdatering for at fremskynde udskriften
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Print formularen
Dim tekst As String
tekst = TextBox1.text

Dim antalSider As Integer
antalSider = Len(tekst) / 3500 ' Antager at hver side kan rumme 3500 karakterer

Dim i As Integer ' Tilføjet erklæring af variabel i
For i = 1 To antalSider
    ' Opret en ny kopi af formularen
    Dim nyForm As Object
    Set nyForm = New Redegørelse
    'nyForm.Show

    ' Indstil tekstboks1 i den nye kopi til at indeholde en del af teksten
    Dim startIdx As Integer
    startIdx = (i - 1) * 3500
    Dim endIdx As Integer
    endIdx = i * 3500 + 523
    'nyForm.TextBox1.text = Mid(tekst, startIdx + 1, endIdx - startIdx)

    ' Print den nye kopi
    nyForm.PrintForm
       
    Unload nyForm ' Tilføjet koden for at lukke den nye kopi
Next i

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) ' Tilføjet en ventekode på 1 sekund

' Gendan skærmopdateringens tidligere tilstand
Application.ScreenUpdating = oldScreenUpdating

' Skift tilbage til det aktive ark
ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `antalSider` is an integer so your division turns out to 1 (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/integer-data-type))

Try this instead:

```
Dim antalSider As Integer
antalSider = Application.RoundUp(Len(tekst) / 3500, 0) ' Antager at hver side kan rumme 3500 karakterer
```

This way, if the length is any amount above 3500, it will give the correct amount of iterations to go through.

For getting the correct characters:

```
        Dim endIdx As Integer
        If i < antalSider Then
            endIdx = startIdx + 3500
        Else
            endIdx = Len(tekst)
        End If
        nyForm.TextBox1.Text = "Test " & i & Mid(tekst, startIdx + 1, endIdx)
```

That should take care of your duplicates

Comment: It gives a print of page 1 in 2 copies.

Comment: You'll have to adjust how you print your text/form or did you leave that part as a comment? `nyForm.TextBox1.text = Mid` etc.

Comment: I have tried both with the same result, still only page 1.

Comment: Made an edit for page1 being duped. This should normally work for any length above 3500 now

Answer (score 0):

Now I have found a solution that seems to work.

```
Private Sub Udskriv_Click()

' Skift til det aktive ark
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

' Navn på Frame
Dim frameNavn As String
frameNavn = "Redegørelse"

' Gem skærmopdateringens aktuelle tilstand
Dim oldScreenUpdating As Boolean
oldScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating

' Deaktiver skærmopdatering for at fremskynde udskriften
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Print formularen
Dim tekst As String
tekst = TextBox1.text

Dim antalSider As Integer
'antalSider = Len(tekst) / 3000 ' Antager at hver side kan rumme 3000 karakterer
antalSider = Application.RoundUp(Len(tekst) / 2500, 0)

Dim i As Integer ' Tilføjet erklæring af variabel i
For i = 1 To antalSider
    ' Opret en ny kopi af formularen
    Dim nyForm As Object
    Set nyForm = New Redegørelse
    'nyForm.Show

    ' Indstil tekstboks1 i den nye kopi til at indeholde en del af teksten
    Dim startIdx As Integer
    startIdx = (i - 1) * 2500
    Dim endIdx As Integer
    endIdx = i * 2700
    nyForm.TextBox1.text = Mid(tekst, startIdx + 1, endIdx - startIdx)

    ' Print den nye kopi
    nyForm.PrintForm
       
    Unload nyForm ' Tilføjet koden for at lukke den nye kopi
Next i

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) ' Tilføjet en ventekode på 1 sekund

' Gendan skærmopdateringens tidligere tilstand
Application.ScreenUpdating = oldScreenUpdating

' Skift tilbage til det aktive ark
ws.Activate
End Sub
```